# Is there any other way to visualize the page object in Ruby Mechanize than PrettyPrint?

Tags: ruby, browser, rendering, mechanize, lynx

I wonder if there is any other way to visualize the page object in Ruby Mechanize than PrettyPrint. For example: to render it in a png image file, or show it in a browser window, or print it on the terminal similar to Lynx browser way.

Comment: If you need HTML rendering, you are most probably going to need a real browser engine, like Webkit or Gecko.

Comment: Thx, I thought that Mechanize itself provide a way to do this.